# Quartz job not retriggering Schedule job after exception

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz-core

I have Application for Job Handler where many jobs are running parallely with Quartz scheduler.

However I have facing problem at time of any exception thrown from Jobs to Scheduler, Job are not retriggering after any exception coming under that job. All jobs are working fine without affection.

I have tried e2.refireImmediately();  method but it not working here.

I am using SimpleTrigger class to manage all jobs.

Kindly assist.

Comment: what exceptions are causing this problem? any stacktrace??

Comment: Any exceptions at the end I am throwing as JobExecutionException